# tsql match abreviation

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I need to match abreviations, where a dot means everything that starts with, like:

```
Rows:
  blue love
  abo love
  comeb love
  blue lauer
  blue alo

(a)

Input:
  b. love

Expected output:
  blue love

(b)

Input:
 b. l.

Expected output:
  blue love
  blue lauer
```

Any tip?

Comment: try using case and then concat them...

Comment: can you elaborate? (I still can't see the solution, sorry)

Comment: do you have b. and l. as separate columns?

Comment: Vutukuri: nop.
Justin Pihony: sql server.

Comment: Please do not put SQL Server in the title, that is what tags are for

Comment: @JustinPihony I Though the problem is not that related to the database engine. But ok!

Comment: @myself different RDBMS have different functions that can be called. For instance, for SQL Server, I think using my solution might be most optimal, however maybe using a regular expression would be easier for some

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could convert the . to a % so that you can do a `LIKE`

```
SELECT @yourfilter = REPLACE(@yourfilter, '.', '%');
```

Then just use it:

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE COLUMN LIKE @yourfilter
```

It would be equivalent to:

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE COLUMN LIKE 'b% love'
```

OR

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE COLUMN LIKE 'b% l%'
```

[Here is a working SQL Fiddle example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/925c3/4)

Comment: @Blam No it wouldnt: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/5f75b/1 The % followed by l requires that l be after b

Comment: you are right, it gonna work! To be honest, i tried this solution, but for some reason when you concat column1 + ' ' + column2 like 'b. l.' you get a strange result (it works if i do the concat in a subquery).

Comment: @myself Yah, I added a working sql fiddle of your full example set. If this solved your problem, upvotes and accepted answers are always appreciated :)

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE abrieviate
(
@delim          char,
@word           varchar(20)
)

AS

SELECT TOP 1 * 
FROM Table
WHERE CHARINDEX(WORD_FIELD, @delim) > 0
AND WORD_FIELD LIKE '%' + @word + '%'

GO

EXEC abrieviate 'b', "love"
```

Comment: You could extend it further by adding more @word parameters in the stored procedure.  I created this for you as a base, I hope it is somewhat helpful.